# How to disable static content handling in Spring Boot 2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a library that is imported into other Java applications. Inside of the library I define a custom interceptor and have a corresponding `@Configuration` class where I wire the custom interceptor into the `InterceptorRegistry`.

Part of the interceptor's logic involves checking to see if there is a custom annotation present on the controller method defined for the given endpoint. To implement this behavior, we cast the handler in the `preHandle` method signature to `HandlerMethod` so that we can call methods to fetch the annotations. It's worth noting that we have used this pattern for years in the library and have never seen any problems until recently:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

if (!(handler instanceof HandlerMethod)) {
   // exception
}

final HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler;
method.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);
// ...
```

Recently, I tried to add this library as a dependency into a sample Spring Boot 2.x application that functions as a plain REST API, serving responses to endpoints that are defined in a `RestController`. The sample application only depends on the library described above and the `'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'` dependency.

**The problem: When I send requests to endpoints that are defined in my controller, the interceptor code in the imported library always fails because the type of `Object handler` is the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` that's used to serve static content. This is a problem because I need to cast this object to `HandlerMethod` but this is impossible when the handler is of type `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`.**

**I want to know how to disable static resource handling in Spring Boot 2.x so that when a client makes an HTTP request to an endpoint that is defined by a controller in my system, the Spring handler that's invoked by my interceptor is of type `HandlerMethod`.**

I am aware of the Spring property `spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false`, however when I set this property it seems like Spring disables *all* URL mappings, not just mappings for static content. After setting the property, requests to endpoints that are defined in controllers are redirected to the standard Spring /error endpoint, and I get error messages like the following, despite clearly having that API defined in my controller:

```
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /about
```

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @MyCustomAnnotation("some-custom-value")
    @GetMapping("/about")
    public Map<String, String> about() {
       // ...
    }
}
```

I have also tried to add path pattern `/**` to force my custom interceptor to always be invoked, but this doesn't change the behavior described above:

```
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(myInterceptor())
                .addPathPatterns("/**");

    }
```

How can I disable Spring from serving static content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem turned out to be something completely different, but hopefully this saves someone the same headache in the future so I'll describe it here.

The problem was that the consuming application was missing a ComponentScan on its controller classes. The outcome of this is that Spring did not create an internal mapping between an endpoint and its associated handler method in the Controller, since the Controller wasn't ever scanned by Spring.

I am not familiar with the inner workings of Spring, but it seems that when you call any endpoint in a Spring Boot 2.x system, Spring first checks to see if there is a RestController handler available, and if not, defaults to trying to serve static content. The reason why we were seeing the static content handler in the consuming application is again because there was no controller method found to handle the endpoint, and this is due to the missing component scan on the controllers' path.

Comment: Curious do you have @EnableWebMvc in that app ? Just wondering most case is having that activate and cause some weird confusing things. I find it strange you fix with a ComponentScan

Answer (score 0):

i think you are closed to solution just my 2 cents guessing here you need to ovveride this 2 others function from WebMvcConfigurer

**configurePathMatch** -> This can conflict with static resource handling, so we need to disable it

**addResourceHandlers** -> This method disables the default static resource handling by setting a negative **order**. It also ensures that our custom interceptor is invoked before the default resource handling

```
  @Override
  public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.setOrder(-1).addResourceHandler("/**") //disabling the resource chain and ensures that the resource is not processed through any additional handlers
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/") // well where ur static path is
      .resourceChain(false);
  }
```